# (Nginx) Redirect to correct location when someone try to access to https://example.com:port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I recently installed and configured nginx as a reverse proxy server, but I have problem that I can't figured out how to solve it. Now I've configured three locations:

- /plex/ with proxy_pass htps : / 127.0.0.1:32400/
- /tautulli/ with proxy_pass htps : / 127.0.0.1:8181
- /torrent/ with proxy_pass htps : / 127.0.0.1:32800

All these location works fine but I'm still able to access to htps : / site:port. What I'd like to do, is that when someone tries to access directly to htps : / site:port will be redirect to the correct location. For example: if a user try to access to htps : / site:32400 would be redirect to htps : / site/plex/, and if he try to access to htps : / site:8181 would be redirect to htps : / site/tautulli.

So far I've tried to use map module and an even an if statement, but none of them worked.

Here's the map module:

```
#Map module
map $server_port $new_location {
        32800   /torrent/;
        32400   /plex/;
        8181    /tautulli/;
}

return 301 $scheme:// site$new_location;
```

And this is the if statement (I've tried only with plex):

```
    if ($host = site:32400) {
        return 301 $scheme://site/plex;
    }
```

This is my current nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site;
    return 301 htps : / $ server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name site;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;


        location /torrent/ {
                proxy_pass htps : / 127.0.0.1:32800/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Host               127.0.0.1:32800;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                #proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_cookie_path / "/; Secure";
        }

        location /plex/ {
                rewrite /plex(/.*) $1 break;

                proxy_pass htps : / 127.0.0.1:32400/;
                #proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect off;

                sub_filter '/web/' '/plex/web/';
                sub_filter_types *;
                sub_filter_once off;
        }

    location /tautulli/ {
        proxy_pass htps : / 127.0.0.1:8181;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        set $xforwardedssl "off";
        if ($scheme = https) {
            set $xforwardedssl "on";
        }
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $xforwardedssl;
        proxy_redirect ~^(http(?:s)?://)([^:/]+)(?::\d+)?(/.*)?$ $1$2:$server_port$3;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope I've been clear, otherwise I will explain it better. I never used nginx before, so I tried to look for some solutions on the internet but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: P.S.: I had to edit all https links, otherwise the post appears to be spam. 

Comment: Nginx is only listening on ports 80 and 443. Requests to ports 8181, 32400, and 32800 go directly to your applications. Nginx cannot redirect these requests as Nginx never receives them.

Comment: So it's not possible to do it with Nginx, right? Do you have any advice on what I can use?

Comment: For security, those ports should probably be blocked by your firewall anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to configure ufw to block these ports.

Answer (score 0):

I find a **solution**! I created a new server block that listen my IP and the port that I want to redirect. Here's an example:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.178.100:32800 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.key;

    return 301 https://example.com/torrent;
}
```