# I can access Django server directly despite nginx reverse proxy

Tags: django, linux, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django Rest Framework server running with Gunicorn with this command :
`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --forwarded-allow-ips="*" partyapp.wsgi:application --access-logfile - --error-logfile - --log-level debug`

I have Nginx as a reverse proxy with the following configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 162.19.70.85;

location /static/ {
    root /var/www;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

}

It is working well: I can access the service with http://{IP} but also with http://{IP}:8000 which hits Django server directly.

I don't think it is a good behavior and I want people to be "forced" to go through the reverse proxy. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few research, I found a solution. The problem here is in Gunicorn :
`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --forwarded-allow-ips="*" partyapp.wsgi:application --access-logfile - --error-logfile - --log-level debug`

The `--bind 0.0.0.0` will open a port to the wild world, so it is a normal behavior.
`--bind localhost` or any other internal IP works well. The Nginx configuration needs to be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and the best way in my opinion to deal with such a problem would be to docerize your application, so that Django app would communicate with nginx internally and expose only ports 80 and 443 for your Nginx container.

Comment: This is a good solution indeed, but in my case I don't want to use Docker. I upvote for the good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I did some test and finally I get it worked.** Here's my solution:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.178.100:8000 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.key;

    return 301 https://example.com/location;
}
```

I asked the same question yesterday ([(Nginx) Redirect to correct location when someone try to access to https://example.com:port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75750071/nginx-redirect-to-correct-location-when-someone-try-to-access-to-https-examp)) and it seems that it's a normal behavior. The only advice I got is to block the port.

Just to be more specific, you can try to block port 8000 outside your LAN network using ufw:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 8000
```